# What is the historical origin of the Jewish Sabbath?

Tags: religion, religious-history, judaism, origins

The Jewish Sabbath is presented in the Old Testament:

> 8 “Remember the Sabbath day by keeping it holy. 9 Six days you shall labor and do all your work, 10 but the seventh day is a sabbath to the Lord your God. On it you shall not do any work, neither you, nor your son or daughter, nor your male or female servant, nor your animals, nor any foreigner residing in your towns. 11 For in six days the Lord made the heavens and the earth, the sea, and all that is in them, but he rested on the seventh day. Therefore the Lord blessed the Sabbath day and made it holy. [Exodus 20:8-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+20%3A8-11&version=NIV).

I would like to know about the historical origins of this practice. Is the practice of having a weekly day of rest and devotion original to Judaism, or can its origins be traced back to a prior non-Jewish source?

Comment: [reformjudaism](https://reformjudaism.org/mysterious-origins-sabbath) says it is a mystery - not shared with other contemporary cultures. Wiki contains the same information.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - In fact that link contains more interesting things: `In ancient Babylonia, the Akkadian word shab/pattum corresponded to the fifteenth day of the month as a day of quieting god’s heart. There are those who maintain that it comes from another Akkadian word, sebutum, meaning the seventh day...It is also not clear how the noun Shabbat was originally connected to the verb shavat, meaning “to rest,” or if one was actually derived from the other`.

Comment: Inspired by the Jewish Sabbath, the Christian Day of the Lord, Sunday (which in  English has the Germanic pagan name day of the sun  but in Romance languages is domenica etc after *dominus dies*) is not the same day. Sabbath gave Saturday (sabato, sambata, sabado, samedi in Romance, from Latin Sabati dies). As said in comment only later some protestant or pre-protestant groups honoured the Sabbath as such.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#5) attributes this to "holy days" every 7 days after each New Moon in ancient Babylonia.

Comment: Why do you say it's controversial?

Comment: @cipricus - because of [this](https://youtu.be/uzzNmsujW-A), [this](https://youtu.be/X9C7BDuqOuY), [this](https://youtu.be/Q5GqkqTgdP4), etc.

Comment: The old Christian churches never had a problem with having a day of rest, but they created Sunday, Day of the Lord, inspired but different from the Sabbath (Saturday). The neoprotestant debates are not a matter for history.

Comment: @cipricus - I wouldn't be [so sure](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79264/is-there-any-historical-evidence-of-sabbath-keeping-by-gentiles-during-the-first), but even if there was no controversy at the beginning, the fact that the commandment is controversial today still stands.

Comment: The historical question is justified: *what is the origin of the Jewish Sabbath*. For Christians the origin cannot be but Jewish/Biblical. Any controversy inside or between confesions are off the point.

Comment: I mean even the term "Judeo-Christian" practice is ambiguous when asking about origin. The question should focus on the origin of the Bible passages (if we can find one); talking about Christians and even controversies brings forth answers about when Christians started to observe Saturday instead of Sunday etc.

Comment: @cipricus - question edited

Comment: Now, you have an answer in Wikipedia, as @Spencer said: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Ancient_Near_East.

Comment: @cipricus Good points generally, but the text you quote up top in the comments is pure speculation and close to being a folk etymology -- as evidence, it's very weak.

Comment: @MarkOlson - I don't have evidence either way. Do you? I think most of my answer is fine but I agree it's put forward on meager 2 links from other comments. I hope to come back to this and edit after a few books on the matter. In that quote I'm mostly interested in the part saying that it is **not clear how** the noun Shabbat was connected to the verb shavat, meaning “to rest.” Suggesting that it is *not* connected in fact.

Comment: @cipricus It sounds like we agree: this is speculation, not evidence. (Note that "speculation" does not mean "false" it means "unsupported by weight of evidence".)  It would not surprise me if you were correct, BTW, and I'll be looking forward to you expanding your answer with more evidence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think we can have an answer based on the two comments by @MarkC.Wallace and @Spencer under the question, linking to

- [The Mysterious Origins of the Sabbath on ReformJudaism.org](https://reformjudaism.org/mysterious-origins-sabbath), and
- [Wikipedia article on the history of the week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#History).

Let’s take a look at some passages of the first article:

> In ancient Babylonia, the Akkadian word shab/pattum corresponded to
> the fifteenth day of the month as a day of quieting god’s heart. There
> are those who maintain that it comes from another Akkadian word,
> sebutum, meaning the seventh day…
>
> It is also not clear how the noun Shabbat was originally connected to
> the verb shavat, meaning “to rest,” or if one was actually derived
> from the other.

All ancient facts are more or less mysterious, but as expected there is a clear pre-Jewish  Summerian-Akkadian (Mesopotamian) connection.

Looking at Wikipedia article:

> The earliest evidence of an astrological significance of a seven-day
> period is connected to Gudea, the priest-king of Lagash in Summer
> during the Gutian dynasty, who built a seven-room temple, which he
> dedicated with a seven-day festival. In the flood story of the
> Assyro-Babylonian Epic of Gilgamesh, the storm lasts for seven days,
> the dove is sent out after seven days, and the Noah-like character of
> Utnapishtim leaves the ark seven days after it reaches the firm
> ground.
>
> Counting from the new moon, the Babylonians celebrated the 7th, 14th,
> 21st and 28th as "holy-days", also called "evil days" (meaning
> "unsuitable" for prohibited activities). On these days, officials were
> prohibited from various activities and common men were forbidden to
> "make a wish", and at least the 28th was known as a "rest-day". On
> each of them, offerings were made to a different god and goddess.  In
> a frequently-quoted suggestion going back to the early 20th
> century,the Hebrew Sabbath is compared to the Sumerian sa-bat
> "mid-rest", a term for the full moon. The Sumerian term has been
> reconstructed as rendered Sapattum or Sabattum in Babylonian... It is
> possible that the Hebrew seven-day week is based on the Babylonian
> tradition, although going through certain adaptations.

As the question is whether a weekly day of rest and devotion is original to Judaism, or can its origins be traced back to a prior non-Jewish source,  the answer is obvious.

- The *seven-day cycle* is an astronomical/astrological idea invented and developed by older civilizations of the [Fertile Crescent](https://www.history.com/topics/pre-history/fertile-crescent) that influenced the Canaan area (Summer, Akkad, Babilon).
- In that 7-day moon cycle, *each 7th day was sacred*, during which some actions were prohibited
- At least one in four of these sacred days was a *day of rest*
- The very name *Sabbath* can be traced back to Sumer

But on this background Jewish/Biblical interpretations can be seen as innovative:

- The astrologically-centered moon-cyclic meaning is replaced in the Bible with a perspective centered on the *monotheistic* principle.
- Judaism promoted a *moral* discriminatory idea of the sacred itself:  the sacred day ceases to be both “holy” and “evil”.

---

Some older Western historiography was inclined (especially in the protestant Anglo-Saxon world) to look for absolute originality of all things Jewish. Until recently there was even a [“Biblical archaeology” trend](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/60049/37321) of simply “proving” the Bible literally true by unearthing what the Bible described. The recent and more scientific approach on the matter is to ask how and to what degree anything in the Middle East is related to the larger context created by the massive and important Sumerian and Egyptian cultures that preceded any others by millennia.  On that background, looking for absolute innovations doesn’t make much sense, and any innovation can be related to some precedent, as a continuation and/or as a change. Most Jewish traditions are modifications (in some cases revolutionary reinterpretations) of previous elements. Taking into account their background is a prerequisite to understanding changes involved in these innovations.

Comment: "Until recently there was even a 'Biblical archaeology' trend"  Biblical archaeology is alive and, maybe not "well," but it's doing its thing: https://www.christianitytoday.com/news/2020/december/biblical-archaeology-new-discoveries-2020-bible-artifacts.html

Comment: @Juhasz - I am using the term in a more limited and polemic sense, I don't mean any archeology related to biblical time and space, but research that takes too easy biblical accounts for true history e.g. a large kingdom of David or the Exodus.

Comment: I understand.  I'm familiar with Finkelstein and his critiques of this form of scholarship.  That was what I was referencing, too.  Though some of the items in the list I linked may have been studied from a neutral lens, others are clearly not, e.g. item 8, "Archaeologists believe this building was an outpost of the kingdom of Geshur, an ally of King David. David’s wife Maacah, the mother of Absalom, was the daughter of the king of Geshur."  Or, consider the aptly named Biblical Archaeology Society, e.g. https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/magazine/have-we-found-naboths-vineyard-at-jezreel/

Comment: That's a good question, which I don't have a ready answer to. I only read archaeology casually.  My sense is that Biblical archaeology is quite common, possibly even as common as the kind of biblicaly minimalist archaeology Finkelstein et al. practice and promote.  You should post that question.  I'd be interested to read the answers.

Comment: What a splendid answer, in so many ways.